# TSQL varchar string manipulation

Tags: t-sql, string-substitution

I have a variable which contains the following string:  AL,CA,TN,VA,NY

I have no control over what I get in that variable (comes from reporting services)

I need to make it look like this:  'AL','CA','TN','VA','NY'

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @x varchar(50) = 'AL,CA,TN,VA,NY'

select '''' + REPLACE(@x, ',', ''',''') + ''''
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing something very similar that I thought I'd post. (I'll give credit to Mitch however)

This takes care of the middle:

SET @StateList = REPLACE(@StateList, ',', ''',''')

Then quote the edges:

SET @WhereClause1 = @WhereClause1 + 'AND customerState IN (''' + @StateList + ''') '

Answer (score 0):

For a more generic answer, when you don't know what your output will look like exactly, use [regular expressions](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/).

This would let you you match on something like [A-Z]{2} and replace it with '$&'.

A commenter suggested this is overkill for this task - agreed, if you can guarantee you will always get a string like that.  However, other people find these question pages later with similar, but not exact, problems, so other options are helpful to have.

Comment: Regular expressions are overkill for this task.

Comment: Which is why I said "for a more generic answer, when you don't know what your output will look like exactly".

Other people find these pages with similar, but not exact, problems, so other opinions are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with dynamic sql.

You need to convert the string to a table
so
A,B,C,D

becomes

Value
A
B
C
D

using a function like
http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/training/scripts/splitcommadelimited/

then you can use CROSS APPLY (which is like joining to a table, but a table created by a function) or you can just put it in a table variable and join to that

Answer (score 0):

I want to know y does the following script run in SQL and not in T-SQL

---

DECLARE @tblName varchar(30)
SET @tblName = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) + 'Table'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql =
'CREATE TABLE "' + @tblName + '" 
(
ID VARCHAR(15),
Name VARCHAR(15)
)'

EXEC(@sql)

### go

it gives you the error

Msg 170, Sev 15: Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '20090714Table'. [SQLSTATE 42000]